# Can you use scoped proxies with Spring Boot 2 @ConfigurationProperties?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-aop

Using Spring Boot 1.5.12, we create scoped proxies for `@ConfigurationProperties` beans. We do this so that we can effectively have property values that are scoped to the user/session/etc. We use a [`BeanFactoryPostProcessor`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v5.0.7.RELEASE/spring-beans/src/main/java/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanFactoryPostProcessor.java) to register a scoped proxy created by [`ScopedProxyUtils.createScopedProxy`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v5.0.7.RELEASE/spring-aop/src/main/java/org/springframework/aop/scope/ScopedProxyUtils.java) and change the scope of the target bean definition to our custom scope.

This worked great in Spring Boot 1.5.12. However, in Spring Boot 2, [the introduction of the Binder API](https://spring.io/blog/2018/03/28/property-binding-in-spring-boot-2-0#binder-api) has made this stop working. This is because when Spring Boot binds `@ConfigurationProperties` in its [`ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.0.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/context/properties/ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java), it uses [`Bindable.of(type).withExistingValue(bean)`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.0.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/context/properties/ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java#L104) passing in a `type` (e.g. `org.example.Foo`) and the `bean` which is an instance of [`ScopedProxyFactoryBean`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v5.0.7.RELEASE/spring-aop/src/main/java/org/springframework/aop/scope/ScopedProxyFactoryBean.java). [`Bindable` checks that `bean` is an instance of `type`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.0.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/context/properties/bind/Bindable.java#L164) which it's not and things blow up.

Does anyone know of a general way to accomplish this? Specifically, to replace the `@ConfigurationProperties` bean definition with a proxy while still allowing the properties to bind to the instance? I've considered delaying the creation of the proxy until after the target has already been bound by `ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor` (i.e. in my own `BeanPostProcessor`). However, at this point the bean is instantiated and my proxy can only replace the bean. It can't really leave the original bean in the context as a target. So I'm struggling with how to do this using a `BeanPostProcessor`.

**EDIT**: I've created [a simple example project](https://github.com/zachmarshall/scoped-boot-config-props) that demonstrates the issue (with the ability to check out code that works on Spring Boot 1 and fails on Spring Boot 2).

Comment: Basically this is a well-written and detailed question with links to relevant sources, so thanks for that. My advice would be to show some code and configuration or ideally an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (or a link to one on GitHub) anyway, making the problem reproducible. Ideally, I would just have to change a version number for one or two dependencies in a Maven POM in order to see it work in Boot 1.5 and fail in Boot 2. It would greatly increase your chances for getting good answers. Otherwise you will have to be very lucky to find someone with the exact same problem.

Comment: @kriegaex thanks! I will add such an example shortly.